# How to change web-page without link?

Tags: greasemonkey, html

How to change web-page without link, using greasemonkey? Is it even possible? For e.g. , I am on http://www.google.com/ and how can I get to http://www.youtube.com without a link?

Comment: Why you want to do that?

Comment: @Gens, there are all kinds of reasons.  Skipping "splash" screens, Automatically returning to the thread after posting in certain forums, auto log-in or auto log-out, etc., etc. And, most importantly, it has prank potential. };)

Comment: @Brock Adams Potential prank for computer classes! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name            _Redirect foo.
// @include         http://www.google.com/
// ==/UserScript==

//--- Do it this way to keep Google in history (back button).
window.location.href    = 'http://www.youtube.com/';


//--- Or, do it this way to keep Google out of history.
window.location.replace ('http://www.youtube.com/');
```

Comment: Thank you for your time once again!

Answer (score 0):

Use the redirect:

Put this HTML redirect code between  and  tags of your HTML code.

< meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.yourdomain.com/index.html">

source: http://www.web-source.net/html_redirect.htm

content is the number of seconds.

Here's an example where it refeshes the page: http://www.adelazzam.com/as.html

Comment: I forgot to mention it, I need a greasemonkey script.

Comment: Adel, redirects added by JavaScript will not fire in most (¿all?) browsers.  In JS, use `window.location`.